# compress size of image (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have this code to insert a image in db and in the uploads folder. Do you know what is necessary so is possible to compress the size of the uploaded images?

...

```
if ($request->image) {
    $featured = $request->image;
    $featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOriginalName();
    $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);
} else {
    $featured_new_name = null;
}

 $post = Post::create([
          ...
            'image' => $featured_new_name ? "uploads/posts/{$featured_new_name}" : null,
...
$conf->save();
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know you would lose some image quality in the process?

If you can live with that, I would recommend you use `ImageMagick` or `imagejpeg()`.

For `ImageMagick()`:

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
```

For `imagejpeg()`:

```
imagejpeg($image, $savePath, $quality);    //Quality has a default of 75.
```